# call gbm model from C++

Tags: r, gbm

I've got a gbm object and I want to use it from C++. For example, use the `predict.gbm()` in C++ with new data. At first I tried to translate the if-else rule in C++ and just output the tree to a file. However, I found that the gbm result doesn't match the tree it generates. For example, when I use just the first tree, the `SplitCodePred` value in the tree doesn't match the value generated by `predict.gbm()`. So anybody knows how to do the prediction manually based on the gbm model?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting Model from GBM in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36267304/extracting-model-from-gbm-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to [your question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186620/rebuild-the-tree-generated-by-gbm-package-in-r-manually/186871#186871) on Cross Validated.

In short, you should be able to call e.g. `gbm_pred` directly from the C/C++ source. The source is available [here](https://github.com/harrysouthworth/gbm/tree/master/src). You can see how the gbm output object is mapped onto the arguments for `gbm_pred` in the R function `predict.gbm`.