# Extracting Model from GBM in R

Tags: r, gbm

is anyone familiar with how to figure out what's going on inside a `gbm` model in R?

Let's say we wanted to see how to predict the `Petal.Length` in iris.  Just to keep it simple I ran:

```
tg=gbm(Petal.Length~.,data=iris)
```

This works and when you run:

```
summary(tg)
```

Then you get:

```
Hit <Return> to see next plot: 
                      var rel.inf
Petal.Width   Petal.Width   67.39
Species           Species   32.61
Sepal.Length Sepal.Length    0.00
Sepal.Width   Sepal.Width    0.00
```

This makes sense intuitively.  When you run `pretty.gbm.tree(tg)`  You get:

```
  SplitVar SplitCodePred LeftNode RightNode MissingNode ErrorReduction Weight    Prediction
0        2  0.8000000000        1         2           3       184.6764     75  0.0001366667
1       -1 -0.0022989091       -1        -1          -1         0.0000     22 -0.0022989091
2       -1  0.0011476604       -1        -1          -1         0.0000     53  0.0011476604
3       -1  0.0001366667       -1        -1          -1         0.0000     75  0.0001366667
```

So clearly gbm thinks that you split by Variable #2 and get back three separate regressions.  I assume that `SplitVar==2` is `Petal.Width` since the order you see in `str(iris)` makes sense.

But what data is missing?  `iris` has no missing data.  And then how do we see what is going on in each of the three nodes that were created?

Let's say I wanted to code this up in C++ for production, I don't get how one would know what to code beyond knowing that you should do something differently depending on if `Petal.Width >.8`.

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: The documentation of `gbm.object` [in the reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/gbm.pdf) seems pretty detailed.

Comment: How can you use that to get the underlying model?  I've tried things like `attr(tg,"trees")` and just get `NULL`

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using `attr`. It's just a list. Use `tg$trees` and `tg$c.splits`, or `tg[["trees"]]` and `tg[["c.splits"]]`.

Comment: I'd also agree with Awhstin that looking at the code is good - I'd suggest looking at what `predict.gbm` does.

Comment: Hmm.  Ok, I didn't see these at first.  Ty, Looking at them now.

Comment: For this simple `tg` object, which above we saw has one split and three terminal nodes, running tg$trees gives a pretty large output.  Any idea how to read this?  It all seems like overkill for what I'm trying to figure out.  gbm seems to say that there are two separate regressions to use depending on the petal width.  But how can the details be seen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the function `gbm2sas` in the package [mlmeta](https://github.com/az0/mlmeta), which uses metaprogramming to convert the R object to SAS format.

The SAS format is similar to C++, so it is both easy to read and easy hack to C++.

Comment: @user2925417: You are welcome. Perhaps you could mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

generate paths in the same chart as the QTD Price chart

```
paths_df = pd.DataFrame(data=paths[:, :10],
                        index=pd.date_range(start="2022-08-19", periods = 11, freq="B"))

ax = AAPL["2022-07":].plot()
paths_df.plot(ax=ax,
              legend=False,
              title="AAPL",
              ylabel="Price");`
```